# Natural deduction (Logic) proof help

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm very new to natural deduction and have been stuck trying to prove this argument all day:

$A\to ¬B,$

$¬B\to ¬C,$

Therefore, $C\to ¬A$.

I've been told I need to use modus tollens on the first premise, but I am not sure what to use it on/what to assume, as I thought using modus tollens on premise 1 would yield $B$, which I don't need, instead of $\lnot A.$

Thank you.

Comment: What is MT? Which inference rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: MT is modus tollens. All inference rules should be permitted, I'm learning from the forallx Cambridge textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the availability of [Modus Tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) rule, we have :

1) $A \to \lnot B$ --- premise

2) $\lnot B \to \lnot C$ --- premise

3) $C$ --- assumed [a]

4) $\lnot C$ --- assumed [b]

5) $\lnot \lnot C$ --- from 3) and 4) by $\lnot$elim followed by $\lnot$-intro (also called Double Negation introduction), discharging [b]

6) $\lnot \lnot B$ --- from 5) and 2) by MT

7) $\lnot A$ --- from 6) and 1) by MT

> 8) $C \to \lnot A$ --- from 3) and 7) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

---

*Note* : without MT the proof is quite simple :

1) $A \to \lnot B$ --- premise

2) $\lnot B \to \lnot C$ --- premise

3) $C$ --- assumed [a]

4) $A$ --- assumed [b]

5) $\lnot B$ --- from 4) and 1) by $\to$-elim

6) $\lnot C$ --- from 5) and 2) by $\to$-elim

7) $\lnot A$ --- from 4) with 3) and 6) by $\lnot$-elim followed by $\lnot$-intro, discharging [b]

> 8) $C \to \lnot A$ --- from 3) and 7) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

Comment: In steps 5) and 6) you seem to apply MT for the *contrapositives* of 2) and 1), i.e. $\lnot\lnot C\to\lnot\lnot B$ and $\lnot\lnot B\to\lnot A$. That's a crucial point for the OP, I think..

Comment: thank you very much for your help however my textbook does not mention double negation introduction, only elimination, and so I don't think I'm allowed to use that rule. Is there a way to prove it without DNI?

Comment: Sorry, I thought your note meant 'without MP' as in 'without modus ponens' - I thought MP was used to eliminate the conditional?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA where does it say that? I can't see it anywhere. this is the textbook: http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/tecb2/forallxcam.pdf however nowhere can I find DN

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm not familiar with Reductio however am i right in thinking this means i can introduce a contradiction then discharge (b) and use negation introduction to get to ~A?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Hypothetical Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) in your tool box, the proof becomes far more direct.

> Hypothetical Syllogism (**HS**) is a valid argument form in which two premises are conditionals, and the rule is that, whenever instances of "$\displaystyle P\to Q$", and "$\displaystyle Q \to  R$", appear on lines of a proof, "$\displaystyle P\to R$" can be placed on a subsequent line.

In your argument, we then have

$(1) \;\;A\to \lnot B,\qquad$ (premise)

$(2) \;\;\lnot B \to \lnot C,\,\quad$ (premise)

$(3) \;\;A\to \lnot C,\qquad$ **HS**, $(1), (2)$

$(4) \;\;C \to \lnot A,\qquad$ contraposive of $(3).$

---

Note that instead of relying on the equivalence of an implication $p\to q$ with its contrapositive, $\lnot q \to \lnot p$, we can proceed from $(3)$ to

$(4) \;\;\quad C \quad$ assumption

$(5) \;\;\quad \lnot\lnot C\quad$ double negation on $(4)$

$(6) \;\;\quad  \lnot A\quad$ ($3$, $5$, modus tollens)

$(7) \;\; C\to \lnot A \quad$ ($4-6$)